# Fire a UILocalNotification weekly doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to fire a notification weekly with a very basic code but it seems not working or the log are wrong (!?) because with this

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()

notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.fireDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(10)
notification.alertBody = "New notification"
notification.userInfo = ["foo": "333"]

notification.timeZone = AppConfig.localTimeZone

notification.repeatInterval = .WeekOfMonth
notification.repeatCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

I get

```
<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x7ffd33615350> 
{fire date = Saturday 9 July 2016 at 17 h 23 min 20 s Central European Summer Time, 
time zone = Europe/Rome (GMT+2) offset 7200 (Daylight), 
repeat interval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth, 
repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, 
next fire date = Saturday 9 July 2016 at 17 h 23 min 20 s Central European Summer Time, 
user info = {
        foo = 333;
}}
```

and the notification is never received but if I set a day as repeatInterval the notification is received but the **next fire date** is equal to **fire date**

Can it be a simulator problem?
Thanks